# Github: New SSH key

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I have very little knowledge about SSH etc. I was trying to add new SSH key on Github. For this I followed this procedure:

**On Terminal**

```
work@Nirvair:~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/work/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Created directory '/home/work/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/work/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/work/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
```

Then there was **key fingerprint** and **key's randomart image**.

**On Browser**

I opened:

> [Github](https://github.com/) >> Settings >> SSH and GPG keys >> New SSH key

It asked for **Title** and **Key**. I gave some title and then I copied my key **id_rsa.pub** there. It gave an error:

> Key is invalid. It must begin with 'ssh-ed25519', 'ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp384', or 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp521'. Check that you're copying the public half of the key

I have no idea how to proceed further. Please tell me where I am wrong or direct me to a good tutorial.

OS details: Ubuntu 14.04.5

*Thanks!*

*PS: I tried to read about "key fingerprint" and "key's randomart image" over the internet but everything went over my head*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you perfectly copied your public key?

Execute

`cat /home/work/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

and copy everything to your clipboard.

You can also try with xclip:

`xclip -sel clip < /home/work/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Comment: Phew!! It was my mistake. I was leaving out `work@Nirvair` while copying the key.  I noticed I didn't copy **everything** as u said. Many thanks!